# Make all ActionMailer deliveries use delayed_job by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to make all ActionMailer deliveries enqueue a delayed job by default, instead of doing it synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `ActionMailer` and change the method that sends to use `delayed_job`. Now use your own mail class to send mail!

Comment: where would this live? As a LIB? Can't use my own mail class as I'm using DEVISE

Comment: I don't like this solution, because not all mailer classes are under our control. For example the mailer of the devise gem is not.